# How to use external bibdata on IEEE conference paper?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I want to use external bibdata file in an IEEE conference paper. How to do that? The following code don't prints the references list neither put the number of reference on citation.
(I use this template: http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html)

```
%% bare_conf.tex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{XXX}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Lucas F. Lima}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Electrical Engineering Department\\
University of Brasilia - UnB\\
Brasilia, Brazil, Campus Darci Ribeiro\\
Email: unb.lucaslima@gmail.com}
}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
%\input{abstr}
\ldots
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
\ldots
\cite{papazoglou2007service}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibliography{bibdata}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove `\begin{thebibliography}{1}` and `\end{thebibliography}`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
    \cite{papazoglou2007service}

    \bibliography{bibdata}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\end{document}
```

Then, you need a file `bibdata.bib` with your bibliography entry, e.g.:

```
@Article{papazoglou2007service,
  author =  {Jon Doe},
  title =   {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  year =    {2016}
}
```

Finally, make sure to run `bibtex`, which is done automatically, e.g., with `latexmk`:

```
latexmk -pdf main.tex
```

Comment: Thanks @Scz, but don't works. It's shows '[?]' in citation and doesn't print the References list.

Comment: Did you run `bibtex`? What does it say?

Comment: it does not work for me